How do I allow an index in python to be accessed by a word instead of a number?
I'm coding a script in python that can contain a huge list of data "on the fly" since they are sequenced one at a time, and I came across am issue. The index can only be accessed by specifying the number of the index that you want to go to but the thing is there's so much data that I don't know where exactly it is in the index.
I want to make the last 40 characters of what is inside the index the name of the index so I can access all indexes by typing in the last 40 characters of them which I know. My code so far is:
   from eth_keys import keys

def generate_key_pair(index):
    # Generate the private key from the index
    private_key = hex(index)[2:].zfill(64)  # Convert index to hexadecimal
    
    # Generate the corresponding wallet address
    private_key_bytes = bytes.fromhex(private_key)
    wallet_address = keys.PrivateKey(private_key_bytes).public_key.to_checksum_address()

    return private_key, wallet_address

def combine_strings(private_key, wallet_address):
    # Combine private key and wallet address into a single string
    combined_string = private_key + wallet_address

    return combined_string

def main():
    index = 1
    private_key, wallet_address = generate_key_pair(index)
    combined_string = combine_strings(private_key, wallet_address)
    print("Combined string:", combined_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

 

This code is used to combine wallet and private keys for ethereum which I need for my business in order to allow users to store their data. There will be many users so we create ethereum wallets for them and store their data in there. Can somebody show me how to access another index by using the last 40 characters of the combined private key and wallet address which is inside each separate index?
Edit
Someone said I can use a dictionary. Can someone show me how I can do this. I don't want the values stored in python I want them stored on the fly like in the index where I can jump to an index and the data is there.

Use a dictionary?

If i use a dictionary I want thr dictionary towork exactly the same as the index I want each dictionary to have a string on it so I can jump there and see the data. Can you show me how it's done

A dictionary is stored in the code I can't do that there's too much data

Perhaps a JSON file if there's too much data?

What do you mean JSON I want what I had before I want it in am indexlikr structure so I can jump there and see the data.

What do you mean by store on the fly vs. stored in python? Dictionary entries can be created as needed and are stored on memory during runtime. JSON files can be stored in disk (still modified and accessed during runtime).

I don’t have your library or the data you can access but I’ll give it a shot. You can try my code below or create a dictionary both should work.
Add this function to your code

def access_index(combined_string_suffix):
    # Access index using the last 40 characters of the combined string
    found = False
    for key_suffix, value in key_index_map.items():
        if key_suffix == combined_string_suffix:
            private_key, wallet_address, index = value
            print("Index:", index)
            print("Private Key:", private_key)
            print("Wallet Address:", wallet_address)
            found = True
            break
    
    if not found:
        print("Index not found for the provided combined string suffix.")

def main():
    index = 1
    private_key, wallet_address = generate_key_pair(index)
    combined_string = combine_strings(private_key, wallet_address, index)
    print("Combined string:", combined_string)

    # Access another index using the last 40 characters
    combined_string_suffix = input("Enter the last 40 characters of the combined string: ")
    access_index(combined_string_suffix)



Hi sir I need to search up the last 40 words of any combined string and it should load it in there. It's saying index not found and it doesn't even let me type in the combined string that I want

I have modified my code does it work now ?
